# Regex to match all hours except some specific hours

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

In Google BigQuery, I have to list all tables that contain hours between 02 till 23 hour in their names.

Aka match any hour in this range [02->23], so I created the following regex:

```
([0-2][2-9])
```

But the problem is it will skip the hour 10 and 11, and REGEX_EXTRACT returns null value for those “unparsable?” tables.

I could try to match all hours first, then exclude hour 00 and 01. But I could’t find a way in regex to add them as exceptions..

```
([0-2][0-9])
```

What would you recommend/suggest in this case? Given that I can’t split this into 2 different regexes.

Thank you.

Comment: are you using wildcard tables with _TABLE_SUFFIX?

Comment: yes indeed, i’m performing regex_extract on _TABLE_SUFFIX

Comment: so, you do not need expensive regex at all! just use something like `WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '02' and '23'`

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant great idea! Unfortunately I have to stick to regex since the tables’ names are also contain sequential numbers in them  : 01_name_17052022_15000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write the pattern as

```
\b(?:0[2-9]|1\d|2[0-3])\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rlBG4W/1)

Comment: The OR (|) usage is brilliant